# Flatlist scroll one item at maximum per one swipe gesture

Tags: react-native

I have FlatList element:

```
<FlatList
    ref={listRef}
    data={data}
    onLayout={_onLayoutDimensionsChanged}
    keyExtractor={_keyExtractor}
    renderItem={_renderItem}
    initialScrollIndex={initialScrollIndex}
    onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
    viewabilityConfig={{ itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50 }}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparator}
    snapToInterval={totalItemWidth}
    decelerationRate={0.0}
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
      length: totalItemWidth,
      offset: totalItemWidth * index,
      index
    })}
    initialNumToRender={2}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    removeClippedSubviews
    bounces
    horizontal
  />
```

Where totalItemWidth is:

```
totalItemWidth = itemsWidth + SEPARATOR_SIZE;
```

**I would like to achieve** that **swipe gesture will move one item at maximum** but even with deceleration rate set to `decelerationRate={0.0}` my list is swiping even 2 items if I swipe with my fingers little bit faster than normal swipe's speed is.

Is there any way to prevent double-swipe there? I'm implementing Image Gallery so it is not very user-friendly when a user can swipe two photos at once.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try setting pagingEnabled = true and check.

Comment: @Maneesh Thanks you so much but this does not work. I've tried but as far as i know the snapToInterval is overriding pagingEnabled prop. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah u r right @sebinq.

Comment: If possible can you share `_renderItem` as well.

Comment: its nothing but Image component :( I still cannot find solution for this problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @128KB My answer below didn't help?

Answer (score 8):

Use disableIntervalMomentum={ true } in your FlatList. This will only allow the user to scroll one page at a time horizontally:

```
<AnimatedFlatList
                    disableIntervalMomentum={true} // use this
                    contentInset={{right: wp('20%')}}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={separatorComponent}
                    decelerationRate={0.0}
                    snapToInterval={ITEM_SIZE}
                    horizontal={true}
                    scrollEventThrottle={1}
                    onScroll={onScrollEvent}
                    data={filteredData.filteredData}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

use FlatList props disableIntervalMomentum={ true }